# sudo without password doesn't work

Tags: sudo

apologies for a dummy question: On my CentOS 7.5 I've added my user to a wheel group and in visudo uncommented the line that wheel members can run all commands without a password. Logged in/out but it doesn't work. Added my user explicitly to run all commands without the password, logged in/out, still doesn't work. What am I doing wrong here? Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you show us the line for your user from `/etc/passwd` and the respective `sudoers`-file? (Please make sure that your system does not save the password hash in the passwd file, otherwise cut it out....). Does `visudo -c` show any errors?

Comment: my user is clusteradm

[clusteradm@master ~]$ groups
clusteradm wheel

through visudo this is defined:

## Allows people in group wheel to run all commands
%wheel  ALL=(ALL)       ALL

## Same thing without a password
%wheel  ALL=(ALL)       NOPASSWD: ALL


[root@master clusteradm]# visudo -c
/etc/sudoers: parsed OK
/etc/sudoers.d/waagent: parsed OK

[root@master sudoers.d]# cat waagent
clusteradm ALL = (ALL) ALL

Comment: there are several shadow files in /etc (I thought should be just one):
[clusteradm@master ~]$ ls /etc | grep shadow
gshadow
gshadow-
shadow
shadow-

in /etc/shadow i see this:

root:*LOCK*:14600::::::
clusteradm:longhashedpasswordremoved/:18137:0:99999:7::: 

in /etc/passwd:
root:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/bash
clusteradm:x:1000:1000::/home/clusteradm:/bin/bash

Comment: Please put those updates into your question where (a) you can format them as code with the `{}` button, and (b) it's easier for us to read and consequently help you.

Comment: These seem fine. How do you initialize the commands?

Comment: How do you mean, how I initialize the commands? from stdin (typing in terminal window) I type e.g. {sudo su} or {sudo visudo} and it asks the password, while it should not...

Comment: { [clusteradm@master ~]$ sudo -l

User clusteradm may run the following commands on master:
    (ALL) ALL
    (ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
    (ALL) ALL
}

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add all this information. Comments are hard to read, easy to miss and can be deleted without warning. We need to see i) the relevant line from `/etc/sudoers` (what you edit when you run `visudo`) and ii) the exact command you use to try it as well as the output of the other commands you've mentioned here.

Answer (score 1):

Possibly, if anyone still needs the answer, I also encountered the same situation and managed to cope with the problem following way:

In the section "example entries" of the arch-wiki for `sudo` command
https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Sudo

There is a possible variant:

1. Open your sudoers file with `sudo visudo`
2. After the `Defaults` section (was commented in my file) add the following line

`Defaults:%wheel !authenticate`

Also, if you want to enable passwordless sudo for a particular user, you can add the next line instead:
`Defaults:YOUR_USERNAME !authenticate`
where YOUR_USERNAME should be replaced with your username.